# How to get path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories' at run-time in installer class (c#)

Tags: c#, path, directory, virtual

I have created below code but its not give actual result which i want.
Code:-

```
 ServerManager manager = new ServerManager();
 Site defaultSite = manager.Sites["Default Web Site"];
 string path = manager.Sites[0].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath;
```

Output:-

The above code give result like '**%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot**' instade of this i want actual path like '**C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories**'.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
```